# mail is not sent by django-contact-form app and there is no error message

Tags: django, email, forms, smtp, contacts

I've installed this [django-contact-form](https://github.com/jezdez/django-contact-form) app.
When I want to send an email to my gmail account via contact form I get no error and I am redirected to my  **contact_form_sent.html**, but there is no mail sent. Can anyone help me in debugging this issue. Is this a problem of smtp server, because I am testing from localhost???

My configurations are as follows, it is similar to [Patrick Beeson's](http://patrickbeeson.com/blog/2007/oct/30/how-install-djangocontactform/) :

**settings.py**
I have already checked other email accounts and their appropiate ports.

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
      #('***', '***@googlemail.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'   
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********'  
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '******@googlemail.com' 
EMAIL_PORT = 587 #465 or 587  
#EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = 'Django Test mail'  
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

**urls.py**

```
(r'^contact/', include('contact_form.urls')),
```

**contact_form.html**

```
...
              <form method="POST">
              <ol>
              {{ form.as_p }}
              <li>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value={% trans "Senden" %} />
                <div class="clr"></div>
              </li>
              </ol>
              </form>
...
```

**contact_form.txt**

```
{{ name }}
{{ email }}
{{ body }}
```

**contact_form_sent.html**

```
{% block content %}
           <h2>{% trans "Your message was sent." %}</h2>
{% endblock %}
```

**contact_form_subject.txt**

```
message from {{ name }}
```

EDITED

when setting `action="."` in my **contact_form.html** and adding `print request.POST` I get this in my development server at localhost, after clicking the submit button:

```
<QueryDict: {u'body': [u'This is my Test message for you !!\r\n\r\nBest Regards\r\nMr. NoOne'], u'name': [u'testname'], u'submit': [u'Send'], u'email': [u'anyone@myemail.
com']}>
```

EDITED

If I write my own view.py I get this error:

```
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/contact/
Exception Type:     error
Exception Value:    

(10065, 'No route to host')

Exception Location:     C:\Python25\lib\smtplib.py in connect, line 310
Python Executable:  C:\Python25\python.exe
Python Version:     2.5.0
Python Path:    ['H:\\webpage', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\python25.zip', 'C:\\Python25\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python25\\lib', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python25', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages']
```

**my new own views.py looks like:**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.mail import send_mail

from contact_form.forms import ContactForm


def email_contact(request, form_class=ContactForm, template_name='contact_form/contact_form.html'):
    form = form_class(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES, request=request)
    if request.method == "POST":
        send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com', ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
        print request.POST
    return render_to_response(template_name, { 'form': form }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the form even submits? Because if you submit a form with debug true, and no csrf token present in your form, Django should give an error. Another idea; you're talking to smtp.gmail.com, but use an @googlemail.com address. Are you sure that copes?

EDIT

I did this different; instead of using an existing app I build a new one. My app needed to do more than just mailing. And it's only two files, so that should help. I used gmail too, another plus:) I'll give you the relevant code, but cut peaces out, so watch that;)

settings.py:

```
from local import localsettings

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    ('Jasper Kennis', 'jasper.kennis@companymail.nl'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': localsettings.db_engine,
        'NAME': localsettings.db_name,
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '###'

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
        'therelevantapp',
)


EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '###@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '###'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

and the app, app/views.py

```
import os
import os.path
import string
from random import choice

from app.models import *
from TitelGenerator.TitelGenerator import TitelGenerator
from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives



def klaar(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        title = 'Je inschrijving is voltooid!'
        message = 'a whole message'
        send_mail( title , message , 'sendermail' , 'receivermail' ,     fail_silently=False)

        return render_to_response('klaar.html' , { 'titel': kind.id, 'request':     request.FILES }, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Note that you REALLY NEED to have {% csrf_token %} inside your form. The form template you'll have to build yourself in this case. Let me know if this helped.

Comment: I've tested it with smtp.googlemail.com, but still the same problem. Is there any way to debug?

Comment: I know I had similar problems once. I hope I still have the repo somewhere, let me look for it for ya.

Comment: I would appreciate any help, because I am getting crazy, with no error message being provided. It's like a guessing game.

Comment: Did you paste your solution here? I cannot see anything?

Comment: Put an action="" (or action =".") in your form html tag and print request.POST in your view to be sure that the form really is working.

Comment: @ Jasper Kennis: I will try the solution with my own app, and tell you about the results.

Comment: @ stevejalim: I've edited my question with your debugging help regarding the form submission.

Comment: Stevejalim has a really good point there, where is your action attribute?

Comment: Even with an action attribute it like this <form action="/sent/" method="post">, it does not sent an email, although it redirects you to the "have sent page".

Comment: What action in what view renders the "have sent page"? Try outputting the request object there. The form data should be in request.POST or something, if it isn't the form doesn't sent its info. Otherwise the problem is in the view somewhere.

Comment: I wrote my own view.py an got Exception Value:      

(10065, 'No route to host')

Exception Location:     C:\Python25\lib\smtplib.py in connect, line 310

Comment: Sorry to keep you waiting;) That doesn't look like a Django error to me (although my django skills are dusty). A little Google gave me this interesting result: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=75621 It might just be a firewall issue, check if the port is open;) At least the fact that you are getting that data in request.POST means that your form does submit the data, so the mail action really is the problem. Also, but totally off topic, it might be a good idea to update to python 2.7.

Comment: BE CAREFUL THOUGH, you probably only need to open the outgoing communication on the ports you wish to use. Probably. This really isn't my area but you shouldn't just open up random ports;)

Comment: Sorry for the late answer and thank you for helping eagerly. The problem with the smtplib.py was that in the settings.py the name and a email should be povided to the ADMINS. But finally it works after re-installing the django-contact-form app. I also delete the egg file and the django-contact-form folder before installing it again. So I declare your configuration as the "answer".

Comment: That's lame... I didn't even think that was the problem. I thank you for the reps (I can now comment everywhere, woohoo) but was it really my answer that helped you out here? Guess not... Glad you worked it out though:) I really found Django's mailing system a bit hard relative to the rest of Django.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your ADMIN,MANAGERS settings in your settings.py is available because it's lookin for these emails

in forms.py of contact_form

```
class BaseEmailFormMixin(object):
    from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
    recipient_list = [email for _, email in settings.MANAGERS]
```

again make sure you set email port host setting in yout settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'yourmailserver'
EMAIL_PORT = "587"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```